# Multiple VAO share a EBO (OpenGL 3.3)

Tags: opengl, buffers

As mentioned [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4623/multiple-vao-share-a-vbo), multiple VAOs can share a single VBO. However, can multiple VAOs share a single EBO?

For example, I want to create 2 rectangles. So, I do the following:

```
const GLuint indices[6] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 3, 2
};

// First
glGenVertexArrays (1, &VAO1);
glBindVertexArray (VAO1);
glGenBuffers (1, &EBO1);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO1);
glBufferData (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// creating VBO, setting attributes etc
// Second
glGenVertexArrays (1, &VAO2);
glBindVertexArray (VAO2);
glGenBuffers (1, &EBO2);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO2);
glBufferData (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

`glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)` is called twice for different EBOs with same data. As I understand, this leads to double GPU memory consumption and takes twice loading time.

So, would the following be correct?

```
const GLuint indices[6] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 3, 2
};
glGenBuffers (1, &EBO);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// First
glGenVertexArrays (1, &VAO1);
glBindVertexArray (VAO1);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
// creating VBO, setting attributes etc
// Second
glGenVertexArrays (1, &VAO2);
glBindVertexArray (VAO2);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is non-functional, but only because (in the core profile) you cannot bind a buffer to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` unless a VAO is also bound. So the part that creates the buffer would need to use a different binding point, which is totally fine:

```
const GLuint indices[6] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 3, 2
};
glGenBuffers (1, &EBO);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Everything else is perfectly valid.

Comment: So, there is no way to avoid multiple `glBufferData` calls?

Comment: @trexxet: I don't know what you mean. I said "Everything else is perfectly valid."

Comment: I asked if it is possible to share single EBO for multiple VAOs to avoid multiple data transfers of same data. However, after your answer I assume that it's not possible.

Comment: @trexxet: "***Everything else is perfectly valid.***" I don't know how you can read that statement and come away with the idea that this is not possible.

Comment: I misunderstood a bit, but now I get it: bind first VAO, bind EBO, load EBO, bind second VAO, bind EBO, bind third VAO etc., right?

Comment: @trexxet: No. You replace the first half of the code you wrote with the code *I wrote*.